# how to convert timestamp result in node js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have execute query for get TimeStamp data from MYSQL with Node JS and the result is :

```
MyDate: Thu Apr 28 2016 07:02:45 GMT+0700 (SE Asia Standard Time)
```

How to convert that to be 2016-07-28 07:02:45 ?

Comment: [Moment.JS](http://momentjs.com/), [Format.JS](http://formatjs.io/), custom code, [Date formatting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString)...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format a JavaScript date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [moment format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/)

```
moment('Thu Apr 28 2016 07:02:45 GMT+0700 (SE Asia Standard Time)').format("YYYY-MM-Do h:mm:ss");
//"2016-04-28 5:32:45"
```